# Multiple options only in one line in select2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, jquery-select2

Is it possible in select2 4.0 (https://select2.github.io/) that multiple select will be displayed only in one line (now with too many selected options field has two line - is higher).
Something like in bootstrap select (http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ example with `<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count">`).
Ex if selected 3 option text will be displayed like 2 options selected instead of showing them.

I need ajax loading and bootstrap select doesn't have it.
Select2 do, but multiline isn't good for me.

Comment: Have you found any solution of this problem?

Comment: No - I passed that feature